# How to get total of given colum of mysql virtual table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
{
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";
echo "<table border='1'> <tr>";
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
echo "<td><strong>" . $_POST['card_no']. "</strong></td>";
echo "<td><strong>" .  $row1['lname']. "</strong></td>";    
}
"</tr>";
echo "<tr><td><strong> Total Incentive: </strong></td><td><strong> Rs." $TotalIncentive "     </strong> </td></tr>";
```

//i want to show Total Incentive Value above table "$TotalIncentive". pls see attached image for more clarification.

```
echo "<table border='1' width='auto'>

<tr>
<th>Tid</th>
<th>Depart</th>
<th>Sub Depart</th>
<th>EARN</th>
<th>Eff</th>
<th> Group Eff </th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Incentive</th>

</tr>";
```

//$sql=Query not show here becz its very large Query

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['t_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['dep_code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['subdep_code']." ".$row['type_code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['TER']. "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#00FF33'>" . round(($row['TER']/570)*$pre). "%</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFF00'>" . round($row['geff1']) . "%</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['tdate'] . "</td>";

    if($row['geff1']>=105){
    $inc=(300*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/105;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=100){
        $inc=(275*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/100;
        }elseif($row['geff1']>=95){
        $inc=(240*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/95;
        }elseif($row['geff1']>=90){
        $inc=(200*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/90;
        }elseif($row['geff1']>=85){
        $inc=(160*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/85;
        }elseif($row['geff1']>=80){
        $inc=(120*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/80;
        }elseif($row['geff1']>=75){
        $inc=(90*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/75;
        }elseif($row['geff1']>=70){
        $inc=(60*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/70;
        }elseif($row['geff1']>=65){
        $inc=(30*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/65;
        }elseif($row['geff1']<65){
        $inc=0;
        }

echo "<td ><strong>Rs.".round($inc,2);"</strong></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

//Total Incentive Should be SUM(round($inc,2))

```
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);  
}

//I want to Show "Total Incentive" Value in the place that i mention in my Image
?>
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `count()`, `mysqli_num_rows($resullt)`, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your while loop as below & echo `$totalInc` at the end of this `while()` loop

```
<?php
$totalInc = 0; //added this variable
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['t_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['dep_code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['subdep_code']." ".$row['type_code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['TER']. "</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#00FF33'>" . round(($row['TER']/570)*$pre). "%</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFF00'>" . round($row['geff1']) . "%</td>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#FFFFF'>" . $row['tdate'] . "</td>";

    if($row['geff1']>=105){
    $inc=(300*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/105;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=100){
    $inc=(275*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/100;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=95){
    $inc=(240*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/95;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=90){
    $inc=(200*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/90;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=85){
    $inc=(160*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/85;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=80){
    $inc=(120*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/80;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=75){
    $inc=(90*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/75;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=70){
    $inc=(60*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/70;
    }elseif($row['geff1']>=65){
    $inc=(30*($row['TER']/570)*$pre)/65;
    }elseif($row['geff1']<65){
    $inc=0;
    }
$totalInc = $totalInc + $inc; //set value to this variable

echo "<td ><strong>Rs.".round($inc,2);"</strong></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: According to your way only able to show total value bottom of the same table, but i need to show the tatal Value another table before to the While Loop.....Plase advice...

Comment: please see the attached photo, to identify the location that i want to show total Incentive

Comment: It is possible to calculate the inc value in query also.for that case you can get sum from query.